# Line break between backslash and opening brace { in in-line code

Tags: bug, markdown, code

in [Necessity of nested \text within math mode for proper \mathchoice-based scaling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172455/necessity-of-nested-text-within-math-mode-for-proper-mathchoice-based-scaling), there are a couple of instances where in-text code strings have a backslash at the end of one line and the next line starts with an opening brace `{`.

since this combination has the meaning of a real opening brace in the output, the two characters should really be kept together.  (i haven't seen any instances where a backslash was separated from following letters at the end of a line.)

maybe this is just a function of the software i'm using to read tex.sx (this software has *many* other problems, but i'm on the road, and have no other option), but it's disconcerting, and if it's a system problem at the source, maybe it can be fixed.

**edit:**  here's a screen shot of the affected area.

[image: screen shot of cited page]

Comment: I’m not seeing it in FF28.

Comment: @doncherry -- thanks for adding link and additional tags.  i'm using safari on an ipad, and i see it (twice) in the second bullet point near the end.  quite willing to accept that the problem is on this end -- but then, who do i ask to fix it?

Comment: Well, according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need, Mobile Safari should be supported, so it’s definitely a legitimate remark to make here. Let’s see what the SE team says. Perhaps you could add a screen shot from your iPad? (Press the home button and the power button at the same time; it’ll go into your photos.)

Comment: @doncherry -- thanks for suggestion.  screen shot added, after several unsuccessful attempts.  (i'm just a disaster at this; i "grew up" with punched cards, and have real trouble adapting to guis.)